# Validate for file format doesn't pass during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have model `ImportFile` and it has `has_one_attached :document` and validate for file format:
`validates :document, blob: { content_type: ['application/vnd.ms-excel'] }` (only .xls)

I created factory for this model:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :import_file do
    association :user
    processed { false }
    document { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new('spec/fixtures/orders.xls') }
  end
end
```

And when i run tests, they didn't pass, i got validation error:

`Validation failed: Document is not a valid file format`

But if i load this file on site it works perfectly.

Why format validation doesn't pass during tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :import_file do
    association :user
    processed { false }
    document do 
       Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(
         'spec/fixtures/orders.xls', 
         content_type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
       )
    end
  end
end
```

`Rack::Test::UploadedFile` does not actually try to deduce the mime type from the file - it just defaults to 'text/plain'.